# Is there a package that allows brackets around the section number? i.e '(1) Introduction'

Tags: sectioning

For purely aesthetic purposes, I'd like to add a bracket around the section number. So instead of

[image: 1 Introduction]
I'd like for it to read:

(1) Introduction

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this.  The titlesec package is probably the easiest to learn.

Comment: Do you want this only for the top level sections, or for subsections as well?

Comment: Hi @AlanMunn, for both top level and subsections. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a standard class there is no package needed at all: Redefinition of `\@seccntformat` is sufficient, i.e. the macro that does the typesetting of the section etc. number.

Usually, this macro is just `\csname the#1\endcsname\quad` where `#1` expands to the section level type, i.e. `section`, `subsection` etc.

Putting a parentheses pair around the construction will do (for most 'simple' classes)

Since `\@seccntformat` is a `@` command, `\makeatletter...\makeatother` is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
(\csname the#1\endcsname)\quad%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Foo section}

\subsection{Foo subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]